# ASP NET MVC array in controller to client side array

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My question is how ( if possible ) from an array like `string[] a;` that I pass it to the
view through the `ViewBag`, how can I obtain a javascript array of strings.

I want to use this because I get a set of data from the DB and I want in the
view to make chart and for that I need a javascript array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy to "render" an array to a Javascript object, using `string.Join` or similar:

```
@{
    ViewBag.a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    ViewBag.b = new string[] { "a", "b", };
}

<script type='text/javascript'>
    // number array
    var a = [ @(string.Join(", ", (int[])ViewBag.a)) ];
    console.log(a);  // [1, 2, 3]

    // string array -- use Html.Raw
    var b = [@Html.Raw("'" + string.Join("', '", (string[])ViewBag.b) + "'")];
    console.log(b);
</script>
```

Comment: Great. One more question. If I have an original array of string and want to have a js array of strings ?

Comment: @coredump see my update -- you have to use `Html.Raw` for that, otherwise the quote marks get HTML-encoded.

Comment: @haim770 seems like a good idea, but `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(...))` is giving me weirdness.  It renders `&` as `"\u0026"`.

Comment: @haim770 That seems an elegant solution, but haw can you evade the problem McGarnagle raised ?

Comment: I haven't encountered such a problem with `Json.Encode`, but i trust @McGarnagle knows what he's talking about. however, your array doesn't contain `&` anyway, so just try `var a = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new int[] {1,2,3}));` and see if it's good for you.

Comment: @haim770 My data contains things like DateTimes and that still causes a bad rendering. In other cases, yes, this seems the best/simplest/elegant solution.

Comment: I need to see an example of that 'bad rendering'. also, according the JSON spec, `&` indeed needs to encoded as `\u0026`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
@{
    ViewBag.foo = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
}

var newFoo = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        ViewBag.myArray = myArray;
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var myArray = (int[])ViewBag.myArray;
    var myjsstring = "";
    for(int i =0;i<myArray.Length;i++)
    {
        myjsstring += "mycars[" + i.ToString() + "] = " + myArray[i] + ";";
     }
}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mycars = new Array();
        @myjsstring


    </script>
```